# Force combobox to create a dropdown

Tags: apache-flex, drop-down-menu

everyone!
I'm working on a sort of AutoComplete component and faced one problem. When you create a new instance of a component, fill it with data - everything seems to be ok. When user types a letter in the inputField (and filter accepts one or few records) - everything goes alright, BUT if the first time user types a wrong letter (filter returned 0 records) - I'm getting a null-pointer exception.

This component is based on ComboBox. I have some thoughts about that: I suppose that the dropdown is not being created at time, any ideas on how to force my autoComplete to create it? I know 1 way - copy/paste some incapsulated code from ComboBox class .. but it would be too many of it .. I'm looking for a better solution.
Or, maybe someone faced similar problem and has the other way to go?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use an existing AutoComplete component. There are plenty of them :
- http://lab.kapit.fr/display/klovis/Klovis+-+Kap+IT+Libraries
- http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/
- https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=19&CFID=4363175&CFTOKEN=ec3c4e2825bee095-DCFF8586-EB12-6C24-534CB18017BF2E01

Comment: @Florian F Thanks for the plug.

Answer (score 0):

I can selfishly suggest that you try the [Flextras AutoComplete Component](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=19).  We have a Spark version available for free and an MX version which is a commercial component with an more expansive API.

Let me assure you personally that extending the MX ComboBox from scratch is a nightmare; and there are plenty of "oddities" that crop up with the drop down in certain situations.

We've been on the market for about two years, have dozens of customers, and have spent hundreds of hours on this component.  I'm willing to guarantee that our component will be more solid than anything you can create in a week, and cost a small fraction of your time.

Check out the [manual](http://www.flextras.com/AutoCompleteComboBox/docs/FlextrasAutoCompleteComboBoxManual.pdf), [samples](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductSamples&ProductID=19), and other [documentation](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductDocumentation&ProductID=19).

Comment: Hello, thank for your response. I was considering use of Flextras AutoComplete also as a Hillel's one, and also as a few others. I was googling for a pretty long time, so I can say that I saw almost everything :D The components were great, no doubts. BUT, I need a component with: 1) support of custom dropdown, which component recieves at runtime, 2) a button near it to make it open, not just a text field (well, that's what I can extend by myself),

Comment: 3) it should be opensource (I don't wan't depend on tech support if I have a problem .. and a few other reasons), 4) It should be free, it's considered as a tiny part of a huge system .. the bying of a component wasn't even considered. The Hillel's component is great, it has a lot of great functions, but it's, let's say - too extended for this project (I've tried to cstomize it to leave only nessesary, but it too too much time). The Flextras Autocomplete also was one of the first considered, but as far as you see, it doesn't fit all my requirements.

Comment: P.S. I believe that this AutoComplete would make my life .. say more "interesting" :) It already doing this, that's why I'm here.

Comment: @Antenka Hillel's is the only one I never hear complaints about. To respond to a few of your points:  1) If you extend the Spark ComboBox it is going to much easier to give the component a custom drop down.  In the MX version, the code that creates the drop down is in a private method. You'll have a headache trying to avoid all places where that code is call. 2) With the Flex ComboBox (or Flextras AutoCompleteComboBox) you can add an external button anywhere that calls the open method to open the drop down.

Comment: 3) A lot of people assume that "open source" means free and you can do anything you want with; but that is not always the case.  You'll have to read the respective license which the code is released under.  Full source is available for all Flextras Components as part of our Unlimited Domain Edition.  They are not licensed under a standard 'open source license' though.

Comment: 4) Nothing is free, by building it yourself you're paying with your time instead of your wallet.  That can be a perfectly acceptable approach and there can be benefits to doing so; it is rarely the most cost effective option.  The Flextras Component costs less than a day's pay for most Flex Developers.

Comment: All that said, I do appreciate you checking out ours and I'm sorry you decided not to go with it.  Feel free to contact us privately if you think we can offer additional assistance.

Comment: Well, the dropdown drops as it should do (the stage with a dropdown headache already passed :) ). Thank you for advice about Spark .. you probably know that better that anyone, but we decided to avoid using spark components in our project (uhm .. because it's still, let's say "fresh"). So I was extending MX combo. And about button - yeah, it's not even a problem, just to add to the list :)

Comment: to 3, I do realize, that "open source" doesn't mean "free". And ofcourse I read the licenses and terms of use. As you can see, these to requirements are provided separately by me.

Comment: to 4, Fully agreed, but in my case I need the component with these requirements.
Well, not buying your component .. it wasn't because of I think that it's not good. Just we have really customized version here, so after buying - there're plenty of work to do ..
I'm sure, that I would need something like your component a bit later for a personal site, so I definately would contact you then .. but this is just a dream yet :)

Comment: @Antenka I'd love to see a demo of your implementation when it is complete. :-)  Best of luck!

Comment: oh, ok .. it would need some time to remove unnecessary stuff and find place, where to publish it .. I'll let you know as soon it would arrive at web :)
Thanks for luck, I'm in need of it .. same for you!